# FlatList is not rendering data from props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array object passed from my parent component called `data`, when my child component is called I check to see if the props were passed in `componentWillMount` with `console.log(this.props.data)`. I see this in console (which is correct):

[image]

Next, I set up a simple `FlatList` to see if data can be passed, but my screen remains blank:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.videoURL}</Text>}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Given how the data object is being presented to the FlatList, this is how I should be using renderItem to receive data from the item correct? Or what am I missing? Thanks

EDIT, more code context:

```
class VideoFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.dataRef = database.ref("music");
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.videoURL}</Text>}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

}

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            itemList: null,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.listenForMusic(); 
    }

    listenForMusic(){
        var dataRef = database.ref("music");
        let items = [];
        dataRef.orderByChild("date").on('child_added', (snap) => {
            items.push({
                videoURL: snap.val().youtubeURL,
                title: snap.val().title,
                thumbnail: snap.val().thumbnail
            });
        });
        this.setState({ itemList: items });
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <View style={styles.videoFeedContainer}>
            <VideoFeed data={this.state.itemList}/>
          </View> 
        );
    }
}
```

now I get an error even before that, with `cannot read property 'data' of undefined' I get this while trying to change from props to state.

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on http://snack.expo.io/?

Comment: @riwu would be happy to but my `this.props.data` array object is pulled from my firebase database, so I'm not sure how to do that without exposing private server info :/

Comment: anything else I can help provide in the original question though? I tried to keep all relevant info and remove all the fluff

Comment: Use `state` instand of `prop` if it pulled form firebase database

Comment: replace it with some hardcoded dummy data of the same structure?

Comment: @riwu yea I tried replacing it with the basic key: a key: b data that is from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html and it works perfectly

Comment: @patelarpan good suggestion, I now encounter an error even before being able to see my console log. Check my edit for more info

Comment: @riwu added some additional code, see my edit if that helps diagnose the problem better

Comment: To access the `props` in the constructor you need to pass them as `constructor(props) {
        super(props);`

Comment: @PritishVaidya added props arg into my VideoFeed class, and I dont get the error, but now when I try and read `console.log(this.state.data)` array object is now null, unlike when I was using props in my console log (which the image shows)

Answer (score 0):

Change the renderItem from your `FlatList`
use this:

```
renderItem={({item}) => ( <Text>{item.videoURL}</Text> )}
```

Adding paranthesis will return the result of the function, else you dont have a return in the function.

Comment: this unfortunately does not work, I took that `renderItem` line of code straight from the docs and only change it to `videoURL`. Any other ideas?